# Distribution of Samples of Random Distribution

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

Assume we have random vector $V$ that contains samples from a normal distribution, i.e., $V = [X_1, X_2, \ldots,X_i, \ldots, X_N]$. We are given the distribution of the vector $V$ as $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, what is the distribution of the sample, $X_i$, which is a random variable, assuming that $X_1$ to $X_N$ are independent first???

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You may want to check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution